# Pagination in for searching

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

table 'sample' contaning fields
    [AffiliateId]  as a primary key,
    [AffiliateCode] L,
    [Name] ,
    [AddressId] [,
    [Url] ,
    [EmailId] ,
    [ShopId] ,

i need a stored procedure for custom paging

Comment: Please give more details on your problem. It will help us give a more precise answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in sqlserver 2005 [reference](http://howto.tawaret.com/implement-pagination-with-sql-server-2005/) or [example](http://noprobs.wordpress.com/2008/07/24/pagination-in-sql-server-selecting-a-specific-range-of-records-from-a-table-or-resultset-in-sql-server/):

```
SELECT * FROM ( SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY id) AS resultNum, id FROM table_name) AS numberResultsWHERE resultNum  BETWEEN ? AND ?
```

for older versions see [reference](http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/82124/) or [reference2](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/130319)

Comment: thank you but last written like that resultNum  BETWEEN ? AND ?,,what this means

Comment: the ? is used SQL prepared statements as a placeholder for a variable, in this case the 2 numbers for limiting the ranges.